# How to sort a 3 pair vector in c++

Tags: c++, std-pair

I've embedded a pair vector within a pair vector in order to be able to have 3 data  types (all ints) within a pair. I am now having trouble sorting by the embedded pair vector. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here's my vector pair:

```
vector < pair<int, pair<int,int> > > obj2;
```

Here's my sort function:

```
bool sortby(const pair<int,int> &a,
               const pair<int,int> &b)
{
    return (a.first < b.first);
}

sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), sortby)
```

Comment: The sort function looks fine except that `std::pair` already has a [sort function defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) so you don't really need to write one. Can you show us what you mean with your vector?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] including input and expected output.

Comment: It's a comparison function, not a sort function. Post your code that sorts please.

Comment: Edited the original post

Comment: Your vector contains `pair<int, pair<int,int> >` so your sort function should also accept those, rather than single pairs: `sortby(pair<int, pair<int,int> > const& a, pair<int, pair<int,int> > const& b);`

Comment: If you're using `std::sort`, the comparator needs to define a strict weak ordering.  Your function doesn't do that - if two elements of the array have the same `first` member but different `second` member, then your comparator does not place them in predictable order.    Edit to reflect edit of question:   The fact that your vector's elements aren't of the same type as your comparator argument will prevent the code compiling.

Comment: Unless you do something unusual with your sorting you don't need to write a sort function, `std::pair` already defines a sensible one.

Comment: `sortby` doesn't **sort**. better names would be `compare` or `less`

Comment: @Peter A strict weak ordering is a weaker requirement than that. You don't need to compare more than one member if that member alone defines your equivalence relation. You just won't get any specific ordering within each equivalence class.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to write a comparison function:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(nullptr)));

    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int> > > obj2;

    for (std::size_t i{}; i < 10; ++i)
        obj2.push_back(std::pair(rand() % 10, std::pair(rand() % 10, rand() % 10)));

    for (auto const & i : obj2)
        std::cout << i.first << ", " << i.second.first << ", " << i.second.second << '\n';
    std::cout.put('\n');

    std::sort(std::begin(obj2), std::end(obj2));

    for (auto const & i : obj2)
        std::cout << i.first << ", " << i.second.first << ", " << i.second.second << '\n';
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```